# PHP and CSV each column data is not getting wrapped in enclosures

Tags: php, csv

I have the following code,

```
function Warrantyform($to, $subject, $template, $replaceArray)
{
    $return = "";
    $str = valString($template);
    //die(var_dump($replaceArray));
    CallDatabase("insert into sales_formsholder 
     (iformtype, cto, csubject, cmsg, chtmlmsg) 
     values ( 1 ,'" . $to . "', '" . $subject . "', '" . $str . "', '')");
    //$handle = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/cron/" . date(dMY) . ".csv");
    $aList = array();
    foreach ($replaceArray as $k => $v) {
        $aList[] = (string)$v ;
    }    
    $aList[] = date("d.m.Y h:i:s");
    $aCsvLine = array(
        $aList
    );
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
      "/cron/register_warranty_" . date("dMY") . ".csv", 'a');
    //die(var_dump($fp));
    foreach ($aCsvLine as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I was expecting the get output like this,

```
"column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4", "column 5"
```

but what I am getting is more like,

```
"column 1", column 2, column 3, "column 4", "column 5"
```

I need every entry in the CSV by enclosed correctly why is this not happening?

Comment: what's the point of producing $aCsvLine? It'll be a single element array that you loop on, outputting a single line of csv. wouldn't it be easier to just `fputcsv($fp, $aList)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would provide the delimiter and field enclosure in your fputcsv call.

```
    fputcsv($fp,$fields,',','"')
```